# Broken pipe while timestamping and appending to log file

Tags: linux, logging, pipe

I am running a python program like this

```
nohup python3 -u /home/myuser/foo.py | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%.S]' &>> /var/log/mylogs/foo.log &
```

The program processes input and `print`s output. It is multi-threaded, but most of the processing and all of the `print`ing happens on one "primary" thread.

**A few times now, I have run into a situation where the program tries to print but hits a `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`. What can cause this to happen?**

I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565744/why-is-brokenpipeerror-dependent-on-the-size-of-the-piped-stream) that makes me think I'm making an assumption about `| ts ... &>>`, like `ts` could die for some reason, but that seems weird and other programs I have set up the same way don't exhibit this behavior.

Comment: `ts` is not run under `nohup`. So if you get disconnected, `python3` continues to run, but `ts` dies.

Comment: But if you get disconnected, you wouldn't see the error message, so I'm not sure that's relevant.

Comment: I converted my program to use the `logging` module, am running buffered, and redirected stdin (`nohup python3 /home/myuser/foo.py &>> /var/log/mylogs/foo.log < /dev/null &`). If it happens again, I'll update here

Comment: Btw, the error message was found during debugging, and was not showing up in the log, so I think you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
nohup bash -c "python3 -u /home/myuser/foo.py | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%.S]' &>> /var/log/mylogs/foo.log" &
```